# How to implement Spring Security pre-authentication for servlets?

Tags: java, spring, servlets, spring-security

We implemented Spring API security for our REST APIs.

The below code is in REST and it is working fine.

```java
@PreAuthorize("@permissionService.hasPermission(\"Get Users\")")
@RequestMapping(value="/user", produces="application/json", method=RequestMethod.GET, name="Get Users")
public Object getUsers(){
}
```

But we want to implement `permisssionService` as filter for servlets like mentioned below. It is not working.

```java
@PreAuthorize("@permissionService.hasPermission(\"Get Users1\")")
@WebServlet(description = "Users", urlPatterns = { "/Users1" })
public class UserServlet extends HttpServlet {
```

Is that possible to implement pre-authentication service for the servlets?

Comment: Thank you...but, how to reigister my servlet in spring component..@dur

Comment: AFAIK it is not possible, but have a look at [`HttpRequestHandlerServlet`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/support/HttpRequestHandlerServlet.html).

Comment: That has nothing to do with REST APIs. You cannot use `HttpServlet`, but you can use `HttpRequestHandlerServlet`. You have to migrate your servlet code. It's just a workaround.